# UITextView that expands dynamically doesn't expand UIScrollview using auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout, uitextview

I have a scrollview that has 2 views in its content view.  One of the views has 2 textviews that expand dynamically.  But when the textviews expand, my scrollview does not. :(

I tried setting the contentSize height to the height of one of my textviews (although I have 2 textviews) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040418/uitextview-that-expands-dynamically-to-text-inside-a-scroll-view-using-auto-layo) but that messed up the labels etc. under my textview (they wouldn't push down/follow the height of the textview).

I just have this in viewDidLayoutSubviews right now.

```
CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;
for (UIView *view in self.scrollView.subviews) {
    contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, view.frame);
}
self.scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size;
```

Is there something else I can try to get the scrollview to expand with my textview? Something I can change with auto layout?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You mean expand as change its dimensions or expand as in change in internal content size?